# Running go mod vendor updates my libraries

Tags: go

I'm trying to vendor my go-modules and am using go 1.11.5. However, when i run `go mod vendor`, it appears that under the hood `go mod tidy` is being called first. This updates my go libraries. Unfortunately, I am dependent on an older version of a certain library.

Is there any way I can vendor based on go.sum instead?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [go.mod changes in travis-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714355/go-mod-changes-in-travis-ci)

Comment: Go modules by default assume you want the latest non-major update in order to receive backward-compatible bug fixes and security patches; if that's not what you want you'll need to specifically pin the libraries at the versions you need: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: @Adrian Thanks! Any idea how we could pin a specific version? We are specifying a version in our go.mod

Comment: Read the accepted answer to the question I linked and/or the wiki page I linked. Both explain it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem I was having is that my go program specified version 1.2.3 of a specific library, but a dependency of my program pulled in version 1.2.4, resulting in a bump when I did a go vendor.

Hostile environment here! I had no idea ;). I will think twice before asking anything in the future.

Peace!

Comment: How did you find out which dependency was bumping the version?